# Is it OK to init Ktor in separate thread?

Tags: java, kotlin, server, ktor

I am looking for library that allows creating desktop JVM app with server feature listening on LAN for mobile client connections. JSON configs and binary data will be downloaded by clients. Found Ktor, seems it meets the requirements.

Can I run Ktor in separate thread to monitor its state in main UI thread? Examples I found create app running Ktor blocking main thread. "State" means connected clients count, file download progress, clients status based on its answers.

Or there should be other way used to start Ktor, e.g. launch a separate process and share configs? Or use another server library?

Comment: Do you mean to use Ktor as client or server?
I guess you mean server, in that case, yes, there's nothing holding you back from running it in a separate Thread (just like you'd do in Java). But I'm not sure if that's the right move. Could you extend on what you try to achieve? What kind of feature would like to implement? Are you talking about a Java Application or Android apps?

Comment: >  creating desktop JVM app with server feature listening on LAN for mobile client connections

Comment: Then I think you can simply start Ktor in a separate thread yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would be interested in using the [`embeddedServer` type of configuration](https://ktor.io/docs/configurations.html#embedded-server).

Once you have created your server you need to call `start` which takes one argument `wait: Boolean` which states on their KDoc:

```
    /**
     * Starts this [ApplicationEngine]
     *
     * @param wait if true, this function does not exit until application engine stops and exits
     * @return returns this instance
     */
    public fun start(wait: Boolean = false): ApplicationEngine
```

Haven't performed any tests to verify that calling `server.start(false)` doesn't block the main thread but from the documentation it really looks to what you're looking for.

I hope I was helpful

#### Edit

This sample code that I have just tried:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit {

    val server = embeddedServer(Netty) {
    }
    
    
    server.start()
    
    println("Hello!")
}
```

Yielded to this output:

[image: Output]

So I would say that `server.start()` and `server.start(false)` (which are the same because by default the argument is set to false doesn't block the main thread and you could run your app side by side with Ktor

Comment: Worked, but on Linux you will get java.net.SocketException: Permission denied for default config, need to set ports above 1000.

Comment: Maybe you had a something already running on port 80? Like an apache from a LAMPP?

Comment: They are called privileged TCP ports, you can check if you bind port below 1024 (upd) you get exception above, if port is already bound you get java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Comment: Haven't tried Ktor on linux yet, but no problem on my Windows machine :o